# ConstrOptim Error in grad.default(theta, ...) : could not find function "func"

Tags: r, optimization

I am using constrOptim function to add one constraint on the best fit parameters. My function is ode function, so I can't give gradient. I wrote as a 'NULL'. However I get this error

> 'Error in grad.default(theta, ...) : could not find function "func" '

```
uinit = rbind(c(0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0), c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))

fit0 <- constrOptim(params0, sse.bigmodel, NULL,data = head(dataind, 20), ui = uinit , ci = c(0, 0), hessian = TRUE, method = c("Nelder-Mead"))
parest = fit0$par
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. The place of NULL is important and hessian = TRUE is not working.

```
fit0 <- constrOptim(params0, sse.bigmodel, NULL, ui = c(0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0) , ci = c(0),data = head(dataind, 20))
```

parest = fit0$par